# Does Visibility = IsCollapsed skip the data-binding part?

Tags: wpf, binding, wpf-controls, visibility

If I set a StackPanel or what ever bound area I have as 'Collapsed', does the data load?
Will it trigger its Loaded event?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes:

- Your data bindings will be evaluated,
- Your Initialized events will fire, and
- Your Loaded events will fire

But in the section of the visual tree under the `Visibility="Collapsed"` element:

- Your controls will not be measured or arranged
- Your controls' Templates will not be applied

So the bottom line is, if you want to avoid loading data for invisible sections of your UI, don't load your data and set your DataContext until after the control is first measured.  Also consider putting any complexity inside a template.