# How to disable all binding/triggering inside a ContentControl

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, user-interface, controls

In this case I have a Grid with a lot controls inside it , buttons, canvas, drawing, animations , all bound to view-models, I would like to disable all the dataTriggers, triggers , bindings inside its children and children of children, etc.,  when I set the visibility of the Grid to collapsed, so it is not wasting CPU cycles, (because a heavy animation is continuously running), and not crashing!

I'm using a behaviour: http://www.microsoft.com/design/toolbox/tutorials/pathlistbox/carousel.aspx

but it seems to have a bug that its making the app crash if the listbox is collapsed when using it,  So I need to disable the databinding which activates the behaviour,

from what I found: [Does Visibility = IsCollapsed skip the data-binding part?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2115210/does-visibility-iscollapsed-skip-the-data-binding-part)

- Your controls' Templates will not be applied

So the only way to do it is putting everything inside a controltemplate:

```
<ContentControl  Visibility="Collapsed">
    <ContentControl.Template>
        <Grid Name="Heavy Animation control">
            <!--- animations, triggers, bindings ,  -->
        </Grid>
    </ContentControl.Template>
```

So in this way the Template wouldn't be applied and everything would be off until I switch the visibility.

So my question is: is this the correct way to address this issue?

Comment: Change the `DataContext` to something that isn't being updated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Since the ContentControl is collapsed, the template will not be applied until you change the visibility to visible.

However, I would be interested in knowing how your grid is set up and whether you could break it down a bit more so that the buttons, canvas, drawing, animations, etc. are only initialized as they are needed.